# "auto.arima" in SAS?

Tags: r, sas

I used to run arima model in R using "auto.arima" to identify the best arima model that fits the data. Even without it, it's easy in R to write a function to perform similar task. However, I have googled for the past few days, and I can't find a similar procedure in SAS. Does anyone know if there is a "auto.arima" in SAS? Or do I have to write one by myself? Thank you!

Edit:
After days of searching online, the closest one that I can find is Automatic Model Selection in time series forecasting package. However, that function is the one using GUI, and still one has to manually select all the different models to test. Does anyone know a command line procedure or package to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

SAS has `proc arima` which is part of the SAS/ETS module (licensed seperately).  You can use either the Enterprise Guide proc arima node for a GUI interface to it, or you can use Solutions->Analysis->Time Series Analysis for a base SAS interface.  The base sas interface is what I usually use, it has the advantage of comparing many models other than just arima for a fit.

To check to see if you have the correct license run the following code:

```
proc setinit;
run;
```

You should see something like this in the results if you have it licensed:

```
---SAS/ETS (01 JAN 2020)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem with proc arima is that you have to manually identify the order of the model by examining graphs like acf or pacf manually, and then choose the corresponding arima model. I just wonder if there is an automatic way to identify the best order of the model parameters. I have a large set of data to analyze, and there's no way for me to manually examine those acf results one by one.

Answer (score 1):

SAS HpF for high performance forecasting is the best in market for time series forecasting nothing can beat its accuracy when u are trying to generate forecast for multiple products ...
 Proc hpfdiagnose followed by proc hpfengine you will hate auto.arima after using this

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give PROC FORECAST a try.

I'm working on a similar problem where I have about 6,000 separate time series to forecast so modeling each one individually is out of the question. You can specify a BY variable in PROC FORECAST that lets you forecast many series at once pretty quickly (it ran my moderately large dataset in less than 3 seconds). And if you choose the STEPAR method, it will fit the best autoregressive model it can find to your data.

Here's a good overview of the FORECAST procedure: http://www.okstate.edu/sas/v8/saspdf/ets/chap12.pdf

Still not as awesome as auto.arima in R, but gets the job done.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

SAS has high performance forecasting procedures (PROC HPFDIAGNOSE+PROC HPFENGINE), which not only selects the best ARIMA model, but can also select the best among ARIMA, ESM, UCM, IDM, combination models, and external models, etc. You can either let it automatically picks the best based on default selection criterion, or customize the selection criterion. There is a procedure family to customize everything: PROC HPFDIAGNOSE, PROC HPFENGINE, PROC ARIMASPEC, etc. If you want to do more flexible time series analysis plus coding, you can also use PROC TIMEDATA with all the built-in time series packages, which allows you to program whatever you want and also do all the automatic modeling.

Like being mentioned above, it is the best in market for time series forecasting, and nothing can beat its accuracy when you are trying to generate forecasts for multiple series. However, it usually licensed with SAS Forecast Server or SAS Forecast Studio, which are enterprised forecasting solutions with GUI. It's understandable since other forecasting solutions built on R and Python which can handle automatic 
 parallelization and automatic forecasting also charge money.

For the cloud computing version, there is also PROC TSMODEL and Visual Forecasting version, which has both forecast accuracy and computation performance advantages. However, it is also for enterprise use and pricey. Afterall, it is targeted to markets that require forecasting for thousands or millions of time series.

For free versions, maybe the closest one would be PROC FORECAST.