# Estimating ARIMA models in SAS

Tags: r, sas

I would like to (insert "have to") do some ARIMA modeling in SAS. Normally, I would simply use auto.arima in R and let the function choose the differencing orders and just specify whether to use AICc or AIC etc...

Seriously?! Do I need to revert to Box Jenkins methodology and look at ACFs etc... to do ARIMA modelling in SAS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I saw this the other day and didn't have a chance to answer.  I suppose no one else got to it.

PROC ARIMA is definitely designed to be a Box-Jenkins methodology.  However, there are a few ways to do what you want.  I usually use PROC VARMAX (Vector ARMA with eXogenous variables).

```
data a;
  u1 = 0.9; a1 = 0;
  do i = -50 to 1000;
     a = rannor( 32565 );
     u = .5*u1 + a - .8 * a1;
     if i > 0 then output;
     a1 = a;
     u1 = u;
  end;
run;

proc varmax data=a;
model u / minic=(p=3 q=3 type=aic);
run;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the licence then SAS/High Performance Forecasting (Forecast Server) includes several procedures for automatic selection between different time series models (including ARIMAX models, ESM, UCM and IDM), based on one of several selection criteria (including AIC, AICc and BIC). You can check if you have a license with `proc setinit`, and if so download the user guide from the [SAS site](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/forecast/).

If not, then [`proc varmax`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63348/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_varmax_sect001.htm) as per DomPazz's example may be your best bet. You can specify your preferred order selection criteria from AIC, AICc, BIC and a few others.

If you aren't precious about using ARIMA and just want automated time series modelling then you might want to check out [`proc forecast`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_forecast_sect001.htm) or [`proc esm`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_esm_sect001.htm). Which can perform basic time series forecasting using several other methods.

Finally, [`proc x12`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_x12_sect036.htm) can perform automatic ARIMA selection using the [TRAMO method](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_x12_sect016.htm). This approach does not allow you to specify a criteria for use in order selection.

---

Variations on this question have been asked before:

- [“auto.arima” in SAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620445/auto-arima-in-sas)
- [SAS ARIMA: estimate without identify? or auto.arima in SAS?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33131/sas-arima-estimate-without-identify-or-auto-arima-in-sas)

And, while the discussion is interesting I don't think any of the answers will give you quite what you're looking for.